# Collect substrings in a list when only knowing start and end characters

Tags: python, python-re

A bit awkward phrasing of the question, but here's what I mean:
I have a large string, called `text`. In it are messages from various different users, and there are certain things I want to isolate within the string. It looks like this:

```
text = 'user1:\nhey how are you\nrandomuser:\nim doing good\nrandomuser2:\noh hey user1\n'
```

What I'm trying to isolate are the messages of user1 and responses. So making two lists that look like this:

```
messages = ['hey how are you']
responses = ['im doing good'] # and so on, as many messages and responses there are
```

Of course, sometimes the other users talk among themselves, so I just want the first response following user1's message. I think something with regular expressions can be used here, but I'm having trouble finding exactly what and how.
If clarification is needed, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really need regular expressions. Instead, scan the string and use prior knowledge of its arrangement to get the pieces you want.

```py
text = 'user1:\nhey how are you\nrandomuser:\nim doing good\nrandomuser2:\noh hey user1\n'

target = 'user1:'
messages = []
responses = []

lastUser = None
isResponse = False
for v in text.split('\n'):
    if lastUser == None:
        lastUser = v
    else:
        if lastUser == target:
            messages.append(v)
            isResponse = True
        elif isResponse:
            responses.append(v)
            isResponse = False
        lastUser = None
```

Answer (score 1):

If your format is always like that(user1 and randomuser1234...), you can use the code below:

```
import re

text = 'user1:\nhey how are you\nrandomuser:\nim doing good\nrandomuser2:\noh hey user1\n'

messages = []
responses = []

user1_msg = re.compile(r'user1:\n(.+)\n')
randomusers_msg = re.compile(r'randomuser\d*:\n(.+)\n')

messages.extend(user1_msg.findall(text))
responses.extend(randomusers_msg.findall(text))

print(messages)
print(responses)
```

output:

```
['hey how are you']
['im doing good', 'oh hey user1']
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, the users have different names, they're all letters if that helps! Sorry I didn't make that more clear.

Comment: @BlueCyclone Then we have a problem here. You're gonna need to tell how you would differentiate between who asks and who responds... with `\w+:\n(.+)\n` regex it will match different names that's ok but you'll get those substrings altogether. try it

Answer (score -1):

```
text = 'user1:\nhey how are you\nrandomuser:\nim doing good\nrandomuser2:\noh hey user1\n'
tokens = text.splitlines()
print(tokens)
```

> ['user1:', 'hey how are you', 'randomuser:', 'im doing good', 'randomuser2:', 'oh hey user1']

I think you can do the rest.